# Ajax post MIME file return 403 access is denid

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I post some mime file to server with ajax , following snippet is part of my code

```
    var upimages = Array();
      for (i = 0; i < No; i++) {
        if(temp[0].elements[i].title !='Mask' && temp[0].elements[i].title != "Base")
              upimages.push(temp[0].elements[i].source);
          //console.log(temp[0].elements[i].title);
        //upimages[i - 2] = temp[0].elements[i].source;
      }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {main: yourDesigner.getProductDataURL(), upimages: upimages, size: size},
    url: "productdesign/" + gift,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.success == true) {
  console.log(data);
      }

    }
  });
```

**everything worked correctly**, but some days ago I change the sever and migrate my site to new server, in new server this ajax call faced **403** access is denied, I check the php post size and change it to 32MB in cpanel but problem exists yet,

**I want to know what can cause this problem and how can I resolve it?** ( all codes migrated without any changes and I guest this problem is about server and php settings ,but really I don't know )

Comment: I think you should find some interesting logs in your apache error log to help you/us debug it ?

Comment: It may be an .htaccess or your vhost, your framework (if using one) that embed some restriction, some IP to whitelist etc..

Comment: @Julqas the .htacess file is the one that was exist in pervious server.

Comment: Same Apache version between the two servers ?